# NSArray - check if objects are in an array?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have 2 arrays. One is a large static group of 600 objects, the other is a small varying group of 10 objects.

I want to take any common objects between the two groups and put them in a new array.

So lets say the large group contains 600 objects named 1 to 600. The smaller group contains 9 objects: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, a, b, c. I want to be able to create a new array that contains the objects 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you sure that you need `NSArray`s? For intersections it would be better to use `NSSet`s. For more information about the usage of NSArrays and NSSet please refer to [Cocoa with Love: NSArray or NSSet, NSDictionary or NSMapTable](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/nsarray-or-nsset-nsdictionary-or.html).

If you are using `NSSet` you have to create a new `NSMutableSet`, which has the method `intersectSet:`, which can be used for your purpose:

```
NSMutableSet *set1 = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", nil];
NSMutableSet *set2 = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"2", @"4", @"6", @"8", @"10", @"12", @"14", @"18", nil];

NSLog(@"set1: %@", set1);
NSLog(@"set2: %@", set2);
[set1 intersectSet:set2];
NSLog(@"isec: %@", set1);
```

You can create a `NSMutableSet` from an `NSArray` using the `addObjectsFromArray:` method:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
NSMutableSet *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
[set addObjectsFromArray:array];
```

It may be that you can also filter the `NSArray` using the `filterUsingPredicate:` method, however I have never worked with `NSPredicate`s therefore this is only an assumption.

Comment: This is a good suggestion with the caveat that for an NSSet, every object in each set must be unique. If your arrays have duplicate values e.g. [0,1,2,3,2,4], NSSet will not work.

Comment: On the contrary, NSSet is quite useful because it doesn't add duplicates (when you add an array to it).

Thanks for the help ComSubVie and MrMage. Its all working now.

Comment: It depends on your problem space. If you want to record how many duplicates exist, even if they are duplicates of the same object/item, then NSSet will not work.

Comment: Otherwise you can still use NSCountedSet.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest (but not necessarily fastest (?)) way would be something like

```
NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:smallArray];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:bigArray];
NSArray *result = [NSArray arrayWithSet:intersection];
```

You'll have to sort the resulting array again, however.