# String Search in two arrays in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have this all country array in my code. i want to go through that array comparing another second array that to check it contains country name.

Example

```
NSString *str=@"Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, American Samoa, Andorra, Angola, Anguilla, Antarctica,"; 
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];


NSString *myStr = "Toyota, Nissan, Bottle, Albania, Pen, Bag";
NSArray *myarr = [myStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

I want to compare this and if there is Country Name in `MyStringArray` that match with `CountryArray[]`then assign to string.

Comment: I don't think that's valid Obj-C syntax

Comment: @Arc676 i made it for demonstration purpose only to get the idea. there will be only one country in my array

Comment: What data types are in the arrays?

Comment: @Arc676 all are string.

Comment: You're missing quotes

Comment: you want to to get the common country names from two arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Intersection of NSMutableArrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023548/finding-intersection-of-nsmutablearrays)

Comment: @Arc676 did you get it now.??

Comment: for (NSString *strObject in MyStringArray) {
        
        if ([CountryArray containsObject:strObject]) {
            
            NSLog(strObject);
        }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers will work but there is an NSArray method which makes this trivial:

```
NSArray *countryNamesArray = @[@"Australia", @"Japan", @"Sweden"];
NSArray *arrayContainingOneCountryName = @[@"Dog", @"Felafel", @"Australia"];

NSString *matchingCountry = [arrayContainingOneCountryName firstObjectCommonWithArray:countryNamesArray];
NSLog(@"%@", matchingCountry);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int originLength = MyStringArray.count;

NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:MyStringArray];
[arr removeObjectsInArray: CountryArray];
int diff = [arr count];

if (originLength == diff) {
/// all diff
}
else {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: never mind, use the other answer; it's better. I'll leave this here as an alternative method.

You can loop through the elements in `MyStringArray` and use `[NSArray contains:]` to check for the presence of the elements.

```
NSMutableArray *commonItems;
for (String *str in MyStringArray){
    if ([Country containsObject:str]){
        //Both arrays contains str
        [commonItems addObject:str];
    }
}
//commonItems now contains the country
```

I used an array because you didn't specify how many common items there might be.

Also, in `componentsSeparatedByString` should have `@", "` (mind the space)

Comment: Yes. that is very helpful for if i dont know how many common items there will be. Thanks