# How do I see if one NSArray has all of the objects in another NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

`NSArray *arrOne` has objects `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`

`NSArray *arrTwo` has objects `B`, `E`

I want to see if `arrOne` has the objects in `arrTwo`. In the above example, I would want it to return `YES/TRUE`.

If `arrTwo` has objects `B`, `E`, `Q` then it would return `NO/FALSE` because `Q` is not in `arrOne`.

Is there a simple build in API in the iOS SDK that let's me do this compare?

Comment: There is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273169/nsarray-check-if-objects-are-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no simple method of NSArray to do this. If arrTwo is always the shorter array, then the best way would be to loop over its contents checking if arrOne contains those objects. Within the loop, return NO if an object isn't contained in arrOne. If it makes it all the way through the loop, then it should return YES.

Comment: OK thank you. Was hoping for something built-in, but if not I'll just do some looping.

Answer (score 1):

You could create two `NSSet`s from the arrays (or replace them with sets, if you don’t care about order), and then use `NSSet`’s `-isSubsetOfSet:` method. It could be doing the same looping that [rdelmar suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25596945/255489), but it may also be optimizes in clever ways under the hood. For small counts it probably doesn’t matter, but if you have a lot of member objects, it would be worth trying this approach to see if it’s any faster.

**NOTE:** this is basically the solution that [James Webster linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596892/how-do-i-see-if-one-nsarray-has-all-of-the-objects-in-another-nsarray/25597000#comment39983187_25596892).

Comment: [NSOrderedSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009980-CH2-DontLinkElementID_1) can also be used if order matters.